# Magento - add productcustom option to Shopping cart rule condition

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I would like to add my product custom option (which programmatically added) to the Shopping Cart Price Rules (in Promotion).

If option value is 1 and customer add 3 (6,9 etc) of such product with the selected the same option in shopping cart, get x% discount(could be different product).

how to pass my custom option to the Shopping Cart Price Rules condition tab. Is there any possibility or I have to write my own Shopping Cart Price Rules?